# substring one field on model and send to view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, model

i have a model and i send substring one field on this model and return to a view for show in gridview
my model is:

```
public class News
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(300)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [MaxLength]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Column("PictureID")]
    public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }
    //public IList<Picture> PicID { get; set; }

    [Column("NewsTypeID",Order=1)]
    public virtual NewsType NewsType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }


    public News()
    {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
}
```

when i send this model by myController:

```
public ActionResult ShowNews()
    {
        var data = new DatabaseContext();
        var news = data.newsInfo.ToList();
        return View(news);
    }
```

it is ok and show properly in gridview

but if send this model by this cod in controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowNews()
    {

        var data = new DatabaseContext();
        var news = data.newsInfo.Select(x => new { Content = x.Content.Substring(0,200), x }).ToList();
        return View(news);
    }
```

show this Error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,NewsAgency.Models.News]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NewsAgency.Models.News]'.

i have send substring one of the field

what is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created list of anonymous objects in this statement:

```
data.newsInfo.Select(x => new { Content = x.Content.Substring(0,200), x }).ToList();
```

And you have send it as model to your view:

```
View(news);
```

But, in your view you have set model type as `List<News>`. So, the exception is throwned. Try to change your code as:

```
var news = data.newsInfo.AsEnumerable().Select(x => { x.Content = x.Content.Substring(0,200); return x; }).ToList();
```

If you want to send whole `Content` values along with substrings, then I recommend to use first way and get the substring of all item's `Content` with razor inside view.

Comment: I Test your Cod But That Is Not True
Show Error In Your Cod :

A lambda expression with a statment body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: @amirseydilo Compiler error or runtime error? Also what is the error?

Comment: @amirseydilo Could you copy&paste here exception message?

Comment: A lambda expression with a statment body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: @amirseydilo I updatet my code with `AsEnumerable()`